# Dropbox uploading multiple files with cURL?

Tags: curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

So I have multiple .sav files that I want to upload to my Dropbox 
I already created an app and have an access token

This is the code i have right now 
How can I make it upload all file with their name to my Dropbox

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/alpha/upload \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <access-token>' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
  --header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"","mode":{".tag":"add"}}' \
  --data-binary @'test.sav'
```

Comment: no, unfortunately curl can only upload 1 file, if you need to upload 2 or more files, you must use something else. may i suggest libwww?

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in ayam*.txt
do
 curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
--header "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
--header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"/${file}\"}" \
--header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
--data-binary "@${file}"
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to a loop:

```
$ for i in *.sav; do echo ${i}; done
```

If that works, it should print the names you will like to upload, then just replace `echo ${i}` with your `curl` command:

```
$ for i in *.sav; do \
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/alpha/upload \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <access-token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' \
--header 'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"","mode":{".tag":"add"}}' \
--data-binary "@${i}"
done
```

Comment: It returns this as an error Error in call to API function "files/alpha/upload": HTTP header "Dropbox-API-Arg": could not decode input as JSONWarning: Couldn't read data from file "${i}\", this makes an empty POST.

Comment: I had a typo, give a try with `--data-binary "@${i}"`